# Почему не работает replaceAll

Tags: java, строки

Есть вот такая строчка

```
"rows":[{"id":"663860","values":...}
```

Мне нужно удалить первые 6 символов (rows":[). Для этого я пишу

```
string.replaceAll("\"rows\":\\[","");
```

Но ничего не происходит. Почему, что не так?

Comment: Потому что в `replaceAll(...)` передается регулярка. Просто удалить первые 6 символов можно с помощью `substring(...)`.

Comment: а не проще ли `json.getJSONArray("rows')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, если у вас JSON или что-то подобное на входе, то настоятельно рекомендуется использовать соответсвующие парсеры, а не изобретать велосипед. Во-вторых, рекомендовано использовать replace вместо replaceAll, потому как последний работает на регулярных выражениях, а они не самые быстрые. В-третьих, если вы все таки хотите дальше изобретать велосипед, то в данном конкретном случае Ваше выражение не работает по причине наличия в исходной строке спец. символов. Там появляются танцы с бубном в виде экранирования, но , его вы используете в самом реплейсе, а контроля над созданием исходной строки у вас нет. А проблема именно оттуда. Поэтому лучше схитрите и напишите в качестве изобретенного велосипеда вот так string.substring(string.indexOf("[")+1); Так вы удалите все до первых квадратных скобок включительно.

Answer (score 3):

`String#replace()` не модифицирует строку, на которой вызывается, но возвращает изменённую строку. Т.е. надо так:

```
String string = ...;
string = string.replaceAll("\"rows\":\\[","");
```